# transferring data from DMS

Tags: file-transfer, talend, filezilla, dms

As mentioned in the title, I want to transfer data, such as PDF files, from a document management system (DMS) to a directory on my server.

I'm unsure how I should approach the problem however.

I thought to use ETL Talend, but I don't think it offer components to deal with my problem.

Alternatively, I was wondering if FileZilla could help me with my problem.

Comment: What is the document management system? How would you get at the files in it? Is it accessible over FTP?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system
i just noticed that my DMS is not accessible over FTP.
i'm not sure but i think i can get at the files with a web services.

Comment: Yes, I know what a document management system is, I was asking which one. Or is it proprietary? If you can't access it over FTP then I doubt Filezilla will be of any use. If you could edit your question to include any interfaces to your DMS (such as a RESTful API or via FTP) then that would help us help you.

Comment: How do you upload files to your DMS?

Comment: sorry ydaetskcoR I misunderstood. I will manipulate not one DMS but many of it (CIMAIL, docapost, EVER ..) beacause we  have many client wich use different DMS, so the solution must be generic and fits with two or three DMS's (Web services ? axis2 ?). sorry Rogier Lommers I don't have the answer to your question, but I'll look for it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm going to doubt that there's a generic solution to getting data out of any of these disparate systems unless they all support some protocol such as FTP. If you can get data out of it using a web service then the API/WSDL are likely to be different. You need to edit your question with how to get the required data out of each and every DMS individually and then we can tell you how to bets go about it.